# Word that describes a person that works with paper and implements of writing

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun which can generally refer to anyone that uses a writing implement as a primary part of them job, ideally something more specific than "writer".

This could include those that author or scribes books, cartographers, draft designs (like in da Vinci's notebooks), etc.

Draftsman is probably the closest word I've found, but I'm not sure that includes authors and scribes.

Not necessarily looking for a word that describes those that produce paper or writing implements though.

The word can (and even ideally be) an old-fashioned or antiquated word.

It is a noun, so the sample sentence feels a bit unnecessary, but to meet the criteria, a sample would be "authors, scribes, and cartographers are all ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the gender-biased word **penman**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/penman) has

> **penman**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **2** A person who writes with a specified degree of skill.

With this goes the more frequently seen, also from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/penmanship)

> **penmanship**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** The art or skill of writing by hand.

Comment: Excellent. This could be a great fit. Thanks. I'll leave it open for a bit, and if nothing better comes along, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Such a one word term does not exist, I believe, and an expression for it is bound to be a long one. What is being considered is the  production of representative visual marks according to two systems: the system of representation by the art of drawing and that of representation by means of symbols (letters, numbers, other symbols). Such a widely encompassing term must be rarely needed, but supposing its usefulness happened to make itself suddenly obvious, it could be invented from existing "building parts".
As pertains to American English there seems to exist a possibility, but I can't think of a British English equivalent for one of the parts. The following  forms are defined in American English.

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grapho)) **grapho-**  (*in American English*) writing or drawing

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ist)) (*in American English*)  **-ist**  that denote a person who practices or is concerned with something, or holds certain principles, doctrines, etc  (*BrE also*)

Thus, "*graphist*" could be defined as a person who is concerned with the production of written code and/or drawing. As this definition is independent of the idea that the production of the drawing or text is by means of the hands, the term may include the production by means of the voice (dictation of text), but the restriction to production by hand can be specified in the final definition; that has to be decided, at least in part, by whoever coins the word.

Answer (score 0):

[Scrivener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrivener):

> A **scrivener** (or scribe) was a person who could read and write or who wrote letters to court and legal documents. Scriveners were people who made their living by writing or copying written material. This usually indicated secretarial and administrative duties such as dictation and keeping business, judicial, and historical records for kings, nobles, temples, and cities.
>
> (Wikipedia)

[Bartleby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartleby,_the_Scrivener) is one of note.

Comment: Hi Hot Licks. Could you expand a bit on your answer? You could add a quote from the Wikipedia entry for "scrivener".

Comment: @Justin - You can do it.